# traversing a json for empty array value

Tags: javascript, json, object

i have a below json

```
{
"loanDetails": [
{
  "vehicleDetail": {
    "RCBookImageReferences": {
      "imagePathReferences": [
        {

        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "chargeDetails": [
    {

    }
  ],
  "commissionDetails": [
    {

    }
  ],
  "disbursementDetails": [
    {

    }
  ]
}
```

]
}
 in the above json i need to traverse every key and if i find it emty then set the parent as empty array ie the output should be as below

```
{"loanDetails":[]}
```

i used the code below

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
for(var prop in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        return false;
}

return true;
}
```

But it did not give me the expected result.I'm stuck here any help will be much helpful.

Comment: None of your objects is empty. Every array has an empty object inside it, except `loanDetails` which contains an object with a property that has a property that has an property containing an empty array.

Comment: You will need to recurse over sub-objects.

Answer (score 1):

The function `clean` takes an object and loops over its keys, calling `clean` recursively 
on each object-valued property.
If the result of cleaning is an empty object, delete the key in question.
If the object itself turns out to be empty, return undefined, triggering deletion of the property holding that object at the higher level.

```
function clean(obj) {
    var isEmpty = true;
    for (var key in obj) {
        var val = obj[key];
        if (val === null || typeof val !== 'object' || (obj[key] = clean(val))) {
            isEmpty = false;
        } else {
            delete obj[key];
        }
    }
    return isEmpty ? undefined : obj;
}

>> a = { x: 1, b: { y: [] }, c: { d: { } } }
>> clean(a)
<< Object {x: 1}
```

Comment: Why do you let the function clean return `obj` and not  overwrite the property with itself when not empty. If only `true` or `obj` is returned, the function `clean` hasn't changed anything which is desirable. I would lose the `obj[key] =`.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON-string is not valid. When corrected, you can use a `reviver` function parameter (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Example.3A_Using_the_reviver_parameter)) to remove 'empty' arrays (aka properties with criteria you specify).

To be clear, the reviver function takes care of the traversing on all levels of the parsed object. If it returns `undefined` the property is removed from the object. The reviver used in the snippet thus removes all properties containing arrays with empty objects, or empty arrays.

The snippet demonstrates this.

```js
// json string corrected
var foo = '{"loanDetails": [{"vehicleDetail": {"RCBookImageReferences": '+
          '{"imagePathReferences": [{}]}}, "chargeDetails": [{}],'+
          '"commissionDetails": [{}],"disbursementDetails": [{}]}]}';

// parse it, using reviver parameter
var fooparsed = JSON.parse( foo,
                            function (key, value) { //<= reviver here
                                return (value.length && value.length == 1 && 
                                        value[0] instanceof Object && 
                                        Object.keys(value[0]).length == 0) ||
                                        value instanceof Array && !value.length
                                     ? undefined : value; 
                            }
                );
// print
Helpers.log2Screen( Object.print(fooparsed) );
```

```html
<script src="http://kooiinc.github.io/JSHelpers/Helpers-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This does not meet the OP's specs, which is to also remove empty arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This should make it recursive. With two solutions.

### Solution 1: empty test function

```
var boolValue = true;
for(var prop in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof obj[prop] === 'object')
    {
        boolValue = recursiveIsEmpty(obj[prop]);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

    return boolValue ;


//test and set empty string
recursiveIsEmpty(jsonDataObj['loanDetails']) ? jsonDataObj['loanDetails'] = [] : null;
```

### Solution 2 recursive empty function that empties parent obj

```
function recursiveIsEmpty(obj) {
    var boolValue = true;
        for(var prop in obj) {
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof obj[prop] === 'object')
            {
                boolValue = recursiveIsEmpty(obj[prop]);
                if (boolValue)
                {
                    delete obj[prop]; //an object is empty. Delete from parent;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    return boolValue; //returns an empty object
}

recursiveIsEmpty(jsonDataObj['loanDetails']) //returns jsonDataObj['loanDetails'] = [];
```

This checks if obj has a property that is an object. If so load that object and check it's properties. If not `return false`, because that will be string or number and that confirms the object is not empty.

Comment: But the OP does not merely want to check if an object is recursively empty; he wants to remove those properties whose value is empty.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks for the mentioning. I thought that because of the initial isEmpty code the OP knew what he was doing. Check if object is empty, if so return empty array.

Comment: No, he wants (I think) to remove empty sub-objects, even if the resulting higher-level object is not empty and thus should be retained.

Answer (score -1):

if you are doing this using ajax then you should go with seriallizing the jason array using javascript.

at the time of passing data through json

```
data: "your data",
```

use this

```
data:$(form).serialize(),
```

it will pass all the key of that form which you are passing ,

if you want to see its result the try to print it on console

Comment: :no im not usig ajax,im using nodejs

Answer (score -1):

```js
var inputObj = {
  "loanDetails": [{
    "vehicleDetail": {
      "RCBookImageReferences": {
        "imagePathReferences": [{}]
      }
    },
    "chargeDetails": [{}],
    "commissionDetails": [{}],
    "disbursementDetails": [{}]
  }, {
    "vehicleDetail": {
      "RCBookImageReferences": {
        "imagePathReferences": [{
          "Valid": "Working"
        }]
      }
    },
    "chargeDetails": [{}],
    "commissionDetails": [{}],
    "disbursementDetails": [{}]
  }],
  "Superman": {
    "Name": ""
  },
  "SpiderMan": {
    "Name": "Senthil"
  }
}

function flatten(target, opts) {
  var output = {},
    opts = opts || {},
    delimiter = opts.delimiter || '.'

  function getkey(key, prev) {
    return prev ? prev + delimiter + key : key
  };

  function step(object, prev) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function(key) {
      var isarray = opts.safe && Array.isArray(object[key]),
        type = Object.prototype.toString.call(object[key]),
        isobject = (type === "[object Object]" || type === "[object Array]")

      if (!isarray && isobject) {
        return step(object[key], getkey(key, prev))
      }

      output[getkey(key, prev)] = object[key]
    });
    if (Object.keys(object) == "") {
      if (object instanceof Array) {
        output[prev] = [];
      } else {
        output[prev] = {};
      }
    }
  };
  step(target)
  return output
};

function unflatten(target, opts) {
  var opts = opts || {},
    delimiter = opts.delimiter || '.',
    result = {}

  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(target) !== '[object Object]') {
    return target
  }

  function getkey(key) {
    var parsedKey = parseInt(key)
    return (isNaN(parsedKey) ? key : parsedKey)
  };

  Object.keys(target).forEach(function(key) {
    var split = key.split(delimiter),
      firstNibble, secondNibble, recipient = result

    firstNibble = getkey(split.shift())
    secondNibble = getkey(split[0])

    while (secondNibble !== undefined) {
      if (recipient[firstNibble] === undefined) {
        recipient[firstNibble] = ((typeof secondNibble === 'number') ? [] : {})
      }

      recipient = recipient[firstNibble]
      if (split.length > 0) {
        firstNibble = getkey(split.shift())
        secondNibble = getkey(split[0])
      }
    }

    // unflatten again for 'messy objects'
    recipient[firstNibble] = unflatten(target[key])
  });

  //Array Check
  var keys = Object.keys(result);
  if (keys.length > 0 && keys[0] === "0") {
    var output = [];
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
      output.push(result[key])
    });
    return output;
  }
  return result
};

var flatted = flatten(inputObj);
var keys = Object.keys(flatted);
keys.forEach(function(key) {
  if (JSON.stringify(flatted[key]) === "{}" || JSON.stringify(flatted[key]) == "") {
    // console.log(key)
    delete flatted[key];
    var paths = key.split(".");
    if (paths.length >= 2) {
      var int = parseInt(paths[1])
      if (isNaN(int)) {
        key = paths[0];
        flatted[key] = {};
      } else {
        key = paths[0] + "." + int;
        flatted[key] = {};
      }
      var newKeys = Object.keys(flatted);
      for (var j = 0; j < newKeys.length; j++) {
        var omg = newKeys[j];
        if (omg.indexOf(key) != -1 && omg.length > key.length) {
          delete flatted[key];
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
console.log(flatted)
var output = unflatten(flatted);
alert(JSON.stringify(output))
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Explain it doesn't produce the output the OP said he wanted. Among other things, this fails to handle empty arrays. In general, it is a bad idea to manipulate JS objects (or any other language) with regexps.